# Set state on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I start learn react native and i see one error when i try set state and use after set but seem not working. Please help me or tell me why it is not working.

here is my code:

```js
handlePressDetailsNews(navigator, dataRow){
    var ob = [{title: 'test'}]
    this.setState({ test: ob});
    Alert.alert(
        'Test Alert',
        'Title '+ this.state.test.title,
    )
}
```

And here is screen after i click to title for see alert: https://www.screencast.com/t/rBkiNbgaTpzQ

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Call your `Alert` function as a callback after setting the state, rather than just putting it after setting the state.  Try this:

```
handlePressDetailsNews(navigator, dataRow){
    var ob = {title: 'test'}
    this.setState({ test: ob}, () => {
        Alert.alert(
            'Test Alert',
            'Title '+ this.state.test.title,
        )
    });
}
```

The main problem is that `Alert.alert()` is being triggered before the state has finished being updated, so by using a callback, you ensure that the state has been set before proceeding.

Also, notice that I changed `ob` from an array that contains one object to just a 'normal' object (removed the brackets). If you want to keep that as an array for some reason, then you wouldn't be able to access that value with `this.state.test.title`, it'd have to be `this.state.test[0].title`. Since the value of `this.state.test` would be the array `[{title: 'test'}]`, you'd need to access the first item in the array (with `[0]`) and then get the value of `title` for that item in the array.

Comment: Here is my file:

Comment: Can you see post anwser bellow and help me?

Comment: I'm sorry your code had other problems, but this answer is valid for the specific problem that you described. I've seen other people with the setState/callback issue, you should mark this answer as accepted.